# C++ pointers vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I created a method ( bool readList(vector a) ) that reads a list.
I want to create a vector on main a send to this method as argument.
For example:

```
bool readList(vector<int> a){
   //Fill...
}
void main(){
   vector<int> my_vector;
   readList(my_vector);
   //work with my vector
}
```

I should use pointers correct? But how? I already tried a few possibilities and none of them work.

Comment: Pass the `vector` by reference: `bool readList(vector<int>& a) {`

Comment: Why not `std::vector<int> readList()`?

Comment: Because I need to check for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you're passing `a` by value (making a copy), modifying it and then discarding the result. You should pass `a` by reference instead:

```
// a passed by reference
bool readList(vector<int>& a){ 
   //Fill...
}
void main(){
   vector<int> my_vector;
   readList(my_vector); // inside readList a will now refer to my_vector
   //work with my vector
}
```

Also, you should change the signature of `main` to return `int`.

Comment: It should (although `std::vector<int> readList() {...}` and `std::vector<int> my_vector(readList();` would be more idiomatic.

Comment: although on debug the vector is being filled on readList, my_vector size is zero.

Comment: @RicardoNeves Then the problem is in `fillList()`.

Comment: I was using ( vector<int> a(b.size()); ) to initialize the vector and it was assuming a new vector. I used vector resize.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a *reference*.

```
bool readList(vector<int>& a)
```

This means that any changes made to `a` propagate to it's source, `my_vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to [pass by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/) in this case.  To do this change your method definition to:

```
bool readList(vector<int>& a){
   //Fill...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the STL algorithms do, you can change `readList` to take an output iterator like following:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template<class OutputIterator>    
OutputIterator readList(OutputIterator result) {
    // For example: Adds 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        *result++ = i;
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> my_vector;
    readList(std::back_inserter(my_vector));
    return 0;
}
```